# Close Milestone with Process Builder

Tags: process-builder, entitlements

I am working with Milestones, and have setup a field update that checks a box on the case. I then went to Process builder and had the milestone close when that box is checked. If you manually check the box, it closes the appropriate milestone, but will not if I let the process run from

Milestone Workflow > Checkbox > Process builder.

Attached are screenshots of my configuration. Any help would be great!

enter image description here

Answer (score 1):

I assume that what you're saying is that the field update for when a Milestone is completed updates a field on Case, and then is not triggering the Case Process Builder to fire. If that's correct, then that is unfortunately expected. [It's a known issue with no fix](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000SU70AAG). Apex Triggers, however, will run on these field updates, so if you feel comfortable with it, then that's an option.

Comment: The KI refers to WFR, not PB but SFDC is known to be somewhat loosey-goosey in terminology re: "workflow" - I don't doubt your answer; be interesting to see if an after save flow would execute

Comment: @cropredy Yeah even though it only explicitly calls out Workflows, it's the same for Process Builders. I faced this issue myself. I didn't try an after save flow though.

Comment: Thanks. I was afraid that this was the case @NicholasSavini. It's such a smooth process but was hoping that it would work that way. I am not familiar enough with Apex enough, so I was hoping that this would work out!  
What would an after-flow save look like? My mind goes there in terms of feeling as if the record is not invoked to be saved. I thought perhaps another change (status or something similar) would cause the record to save and milestone to close. I use this process by marking a date resolution time, & it will close it from within the case. But when setup from entitlements,it doesnt